# group by then compare values in rows of type list to populate new column

Tags: python, pandas, list, compare, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this

```
data = {'clusterId':[1,1,2,2,2], 'IM1':[[0,1], [2,3], [3,5],[4,5],[3,6]],
        'IM2':[[1,2],[2,0],[9,0],[8,7],[8,2]]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 


clusterId  IM1    IM2   
1         [0,1]   [1,2]
1         [2,3]   [2,0]
2         [3,5]   [9,0]
2         [4,5]   [8,7]
2         [3,6]   [8,2]
```

I want to populate new column say "exists" if any of the item in list IM1 which falls in same cluster  matches with one another

```
clusterId  IM1    IM2    Exists
1         [0,1]   [1,2]   N
1         [2,3]   [2,0]   N
2         [3,5]   [9,0]   Y
2         [4,5]   [8,7]   Y
2         [7,6]   [8,2]   N
```

then I want to update column Exists wherever values are "N"
based on values in cloumn IM2 like if any of the values in list matches

so the resultant dataframe will look like this

```
clusterId  IM1    IM2    Exists
1         [0,1]   [1,2]   Y
1         [2,3]   [2,0]   Y
2         [3,5]   [9,0]   Y
2         [4,5]   [8,7]   Y
2         [7,6]   [8,2]   Y
```

is there any python way to do this.
Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: It is very hard to understand your sample data and what you are trying to do ? Can you specify your Exists 'Y' and 'N' logic in bit more detail.

Comment: I am doing this based on clusterIds. suppose for clusterId 1 if the one of the value in list is matching then your Exists flag is "Y" here is the dataframe if you want to create one data = {'clusterId':[1,1,2,2,2], 'IM1':[[0,1], [2,3], [3,5],[4,5],[3,6]],
        'IM2':[[1,2],[2,0],[9,0],[8,7],[8,2]]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Comment: Can you explain how do you get  [3,5]   [9,0]   Y  .. for this particular  row?

Comment: its because for clusterId 2   values [3,5] [4,5]  has one common item which is 5 but [7,6] dont share any common item thats why that is "N" initialy

Comment: [7, 6] and [8, 2] don't share a common value, so the last row should be an N even after the second pass. No?

Answer (score 1):

This would do what you are looking for. I have eliminated the intermediate column steps using function. You can add those back by editing function as needed-

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {'clusterId':[1,1,2,2,2], 'IM1':[[0,1], [2,3], [3,5],[4,5],[3,6]],
        'IM2':[[1,2],[2,0],[9,0],[8,7],[8,2]]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

def concat_list(list1): #Flatten the array values by clusterId
    return np.concatenate(list1)

def count_element(row): #count row wise element frequency

    list1 = row['array1']
    element1 = row['IM1']

    t1 = np.count_nonzero(list1 == element1[0])
    t2 = np.count_nonzero(list1 == element1[1])
    if t1 >=2 or t2 >=2: result1 = "Y" 
    else: result1 = "N"

    list2 = row['array2']
    element2 = row['IM2']

    t3 = np.count_nonzero(list2 == element2[0])
    t4 = np.count_nonzero(list2 == element2[1])
    if t3 >=2 or t4 >=2: result2 = "Y" 
    else: result2 = "N"

    if (result1 == 'N' and result2 == 'N'):
        result = 'N'
    else: result = 'Y'

    return result

for clusterId in cluster_list:
    print(clusterId)
    df2 = df.loc[df['clusterId'] == clusterId].reset_index()
    array1 = concat_list(df2['IM1'])
    array2 = concat_list(df2['IM2'])
    mask = df.clusterId==clusterId
    df.loc[mask, 'array1']=df[mask].apply(lambda x: array1,axis=1) # Add array based on IM1 
    df.loc[mask, 'array2']=df[mask].apply(lambda x: array2,axis=1)  # Add array based on IM2

df['exist_final'] = df.apply(lambda row: count_element(row), axis = 1)
```